# Java import vs code performance

Tags: java, import

I am wondering if i included many `import` in my java program, would it affect the performance of my code (for example, program will be slower)? Is the logic behind the `import` in Java the same as `include` in C?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> **would it affect the performance of my code (for example, program will be slower)?**

No, it wouldn't affect performance of your code.

The binaries (the class files) do not increase in size as the import is *not* implemented with any cut-and-paste mechanism.

It is merely a syntactic sugar for avoiding to have to write for instance

```
java.util.List<java.math.BigInteger> myList =
        new java.util.ArrayList<java.math.BigInteger>();
```

Here is a little test demonstrating this:

```
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp$ cat Test.java 
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp$ javac Test.java
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp$ md5sum Test.class 
523036e294b17377b4078ea1cb8e7940  Test.class
```

(modifying `Test.java`)

```
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp$ cat Test.java 


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.List<Integer> myInts = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp$ javac Test.java
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp$ md5sum Test.class 
523036e294b17377b4078ea1cb8e7940  Test.class
```

> **Is the logic behind the import in Java the same as include in C?**

No, an `#include` is a preprocessor directive and is implemented with a cut-and-paste mechanism.

Comment: Not going to -1, but it can be more than syntactic sugar.

Comment: Like what? My understanding is that with import vs without import would look differently only up until the IR in the compiler. (Check out my example in the updated answer.)

Comment: That's essentially what I was busy answering. It can increase the compile time of your code under certain circumstances (namely `.*`)

Comment: @pst, an explanation what constant pool is would have suffice too

Comment: @bestsss It would be a nice addition for a more holistic answer, but it's hard argue with "bit-identical output".

Comment: @pst, imagine the one says that it didn't affect that case only due to... etc.

Comment: @pst, i mean due to... (like the 1st comment)

Comment: @corsiKa I'd say just because there's a cost with desugaring something, doesn't make it not syntactic sugar.  There's almost always going to be a cost difference, even if it's just a minor one due to a different number of characters being parsed or a different code path.  It just happens to be a more expensive cost in this case.

Answer (score 24):

> ... would it affect the performance of my code

Not in the slightest.  In fact, the compiled classes (using imports or not) will be identical.  An import is merely syntactic sugar that allows you to use a shorter name for an external class or (with a static import) class member in your source code.  In other words, it allows you to write:

```
    Map map = new HashMap();
```

instead of

```
    java.util.Map map = new java.util.HashMap();
```

That is all.

There is potentially a small (tiny) difference in compilation times.  But, AFAIK, something like `import java.util.*;` does NOT cause all of the `java.util` classes to be loaded by the compiler.  Rather it just adds the *names* of the classes to the symbol table.

Having said that:

- Unnecessary imports are a bad idea, because they clutter up the code and could mislead someone reading the code.
- Wildcard imports (`.*`) can lead to unexpected collisions.
- A lot of people (myself included) dislike wildcard imports because they prefer to see a list of the actual classes used.

> Is the logic behind the import in Java the same as include in C?

No it is not.

A C / C++ include directive injects arbitrary<sup>1</sup> C / C++ "code" into the source stream.  This can include declarations and executable statements ... which can affect both performance, execution memory footprint and the size of the executable.

---

<sup>1 - That is, whatever the authors of the include file chose to put into the file.  It could be simple method and class "signatures", but it could also be macro's, code and other declarations that are impactful.  You have to examine the file to be sure.</sup>

Answer (score 16):

It will have no impact on the **~run~time speed** of your program.

It may have an impact on the **~compile~time speed** of your program.

If you `import java.util.*;` it will load all of the java.util package into the compiler, which may increase the compile time when you `.*` an entire package for a single usage (although you should perform some profiling if it's going to be a concern.)

In addition to *potential* compile time issues, don't forget to consider the readability issues. Generally, I (and people I've talked with) find `import pack.age.Class;` to be more readable than `import pack.age.*;` - have a talk with your team of course before making a decision about this.

But the logic behind it is very different from `#include` and does not bloat the code. You may end up with more than necessary as you include dependency jars, but that's probably not a big issue.

Comment: Trying to keep *compile time speed* in mind when writing code seems like a Bad Idea. You go benchmark this, find out if there is any significant difference and come back with your results :-)

Comment: Well, on one side of the coin I see it being it a big deal because you want as fast of a compile as possible so your developers don't get distracted and go on SO or something (not that I need a build as an excuse to get distracted...) On the other side, I completely agree with you that worrying about compile time seems like a Bad Idea. I'm not saying the difference is worth worrying about. But there is a small difference. About as small as the difference between `synchronized void foo() { }` and `void foo() { synchronized(this) { } }`

Comment: You have any references for this?

Comment: For the speeds? Yes I do. http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm031.shtml For the synchronized? There's one extra bytecode in the second one because there's a synchronized instruction, where as on the first one it's baked into the method modifiers (which in theory could make or break an inline/JIT, but incredibly unlikely).

Comment: Still no benchmark tests though. That would be interesting to have.

Comment: -1: glowcoder, your reference merely states in passing that compilation "is probably more costly". I don't consider that sufficient justification to say "can greatly increase the compile time". What makes you assume that resolving class names even takes a significiant proportion of the compilation time?

Comment: It was a good enough source for the #14 rep'd SO user Pascal Thrivent on SO question 1983435. I put 'can' in that sentence, not 'will'. No, I don't have a benchmark. I can say that at my work, my team inherited a 3million+ LoC program: it has over 13,000 files, and it's stuffed into 20 top level folders. No code is more than one folder down from the main folder. Its all `module/filename.ext`. They also like code-generators (bad.) So I could totally see a situation where an auto-generated piece of code imported .* with massive libraries to search.

Comment: I should also point out that downvote criteria is "This answer is not useful." You might say that it would be more useful with benchmarks (like aioobe) but the fact that you disagree with one sentence doesn't invalidate the rest: the first two bullet points are the bread and butter, which is exactly the purpose of the question.

Comment: @glowcoder - the fact that you cannot find any benchmark that quantifies the supposed extra cost of wild card imports should be telling you something.  Certainly, it is telling me that the extra cost is likely to be a myth.  And I can see why someone would downvote you for propagating myths.

Comment: @glowcoder - also your work experience doesn't address the issue.  You have not presented any evidence that it is the wildcard imports that makes your codebase slow to compile.

Comment: I presented it as something to investigate. I don't think anyone here is debating that it must be slower (even if insignificantly) and that the only question is magnitude. The OP asked if there were differences, and I illustrated them to the best of my knowledge. I presented an area for exploration if it is deemed necessary: it was never intended to be taken to the extreme that @meriton took it. The bottom line is, I'd rather not be spending my time benchmarking a condition that is a poor practice (for different reasons than compile time performance.)

Comment: "can greatly increase the compile time" is an assertion of fact. By using "greatly", it also makes a claim of magnitude. If you wanted to present it as something to investigate, and make no claim on magnitude, you should have written "might affect compile time" instead. The assertion is given without sufficient evidence, and likely to be false. Factual inaccuracy is about the only reason I downvote answers, because a misleading answer is worse than none.

Comment: As for Pascal not getting a downvote, that's because he merely claims: "is *probably* going to take (*a bit*) longer for the compiler". "greatly" is more than "a bit", and "can" more than "will probably". And by the way, if you were aware of that duplicate question, why did you not link to it?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it until it was called into question. I'm happy to rephrase the problem piece if you feel it's misleading. I think it's a logical extensions that it's possible to have a scenario where it's true (when my firm compiles their Progress codebase, it takes over an hour... and they don't care a smidgen... I could see them migrating to Java and having it be just as horrendus. I cannot imagine this is an isolated philosophy in our line of work!)

Comment: Modified wording on the magnitude, also added the bit about readability (which imo is a far greater concern.)

Comment: *"If you import java.util.*; it will load all of the java.util package into the compiler ..."*.  My gut feeling is that this is **unlikely** to be true.  It is certainly NOT necessary.  It would be simple for the compiler to add stub symbol table entries for the class names that "match", and only read / load the actual classes if the code being compiled used the classes.

Comment: You know, you might be right. As I look back on this guy a few years later, it occurs to me that I didn't even touch on the biggest issue with `.*` importing, collisions. How many times has `java.awt.List` been a thorn in your side for a few seconds?

Answer (score 2):

`import` does not slow your program. It is better to have different kinds of `classes` in different `packages` and import them as needed. Improves code readability.

Comment: what do you mean by "better to have different kinds of classes in different packages" thanks

Comment: @newbie I meant it is a good design to have different classes in different packages and import them as necessary. Probably it is not directly related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Importing is not an issue.
You can import everything you want from package and execution of your code will not get slower. **import** is for convenience so you can use shorter names.

The classes are loaded when their constructor is called implicitly or explicitly (**new** operator). In case of enums it will be when you refer to enum names in your code. This will cause class (enum) to be loaded. (You can try using println in private constructor of enum to experiment and see when  enum gets loaded).
Loading a class takes time and memory. Generally speaking loaded classes are not meant to be unloaded.