# Java Import Package

Tags: java, memory, import, package

my question is about this code:

```
import java.util.*;
```

I was told that this code will import all Java packages, but my question is:
Does it consume more memory? Because in the program I'm doing I am just using:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

and

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This doesn't import all java packages, but all java classes in the `java.util` package. It won't consume additional runtime memory, as it is only relevant during compilation. Compilation may be a little bit slower, but that will hardly be noticeable.

Comment: @geert3 that seems like a complete answer to me - why put as comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java import vs code performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125404/java-import-vs-code-performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, lazy imports have no impact on the resulting program. See this question: [Java import vs code performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125404/java-import-vs-code-performance)

Using lazy imports vs explicit imports is more a question of readability. (Also, if you reference a class name that is present in two packages, you need an explicit import to resolve the ambiguity.)

Answer (score 2):

> I was told that this code will import all Java packages

No, it just tells compiler which packages should it search for details about class/interface when we used in code only simple name like `List` instead of full name `java.util.List` (compiler needs to change each simple name into its full name).

Generally it is better to avoid `*` since it can cause problems when few packages have classes with same name. For instance lets add this imports

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
```

and use `List`. Compiler will not know which `List` we meant here (java.awt.List, or java.util.List) and will return error. We can solve it by describing precise location of List which we want to use by adding

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;// <-- solves List problem
```

but to avoid such problems we should try to avoid `*` in first place, especially since our IDEs can generate imports for us.