# Importing few Classes impact on performance

Tags: java, arrays, performance, data-structures, import

I am building a data structure and I imported 2 classes which can have been skipped like I used `Arrays.newInstance()` for creating new array instead of traditional method,so I imported `java.lang.reflect.Array`. 
Before printing my array, i am removing all null elements and decreasing array size and when new element will be added, there is `resize()` method which will create new array and assign it to original array.
***So, how much it is affecting my performance.***

I read [Java import vs code performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125404/java-import-vs-code-performance) , which says that it does not affect but if I am including new classes in my project why it is not affecting my performance.

Comment: "if I am including new classes in my project why it is not affecting my performance" - because that's not what an `import` does. An `import` statement just lets you refer to types by their simple names instead of their full names. It doesn't change the generated bytecode at all. It certainly doesn't add the `Array` class code into the output of the compiler, or anything like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Can you tell me is there any benefit of using Array.newInstance() to create new array of generic type. As I was looking in oracle document which says it can be used to create dynamic array of arbitrary type but I am not getting exact idea. I want solid points because my marks are deducted for using this.

Comment: That's an entirely different question to the one being asked here. Please limit yourself to one question per post. If you want to know about that, ask a new question with full sample code etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet you can see very first line is about this.

Comment: No, your question asks about the cost of an import statement `java.lang.reflect.Array`. That's entirely different to asking whether there is any benefit to using `Array.newInstance()` to create arrays. If you meant to ask the latter question, why ask about the import? At best, the question is highly unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sorry I got your point, I am new to community, So slowly grasping the rules,

Comment: There may or may not be a speed difference between `new Whatever[n]` and `Arrays.newInstance` in either direction, but it's not worth thinking about. Just use the simpler. +++ "when new element will be added, there is resize() method" - this is a probable problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you `import` a class or package into your code, you are not actually adding the code to your project. You are simply letting the compiler know that you are using the shorthand names for that specific class or package instead of the full title. As the [docs tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) says:

> You can use a package member's simple name if the code you are writing is in the same package as that member or if that member has been imported.
>   However, if you are trying to use a member from a different package and that package has not been imported, you must use the member's fully qualified name

So when you `import`, say for instance, the `Rectangle` class, you are just telling the compiler that when you type `Rectangle` you mean `graphics.Rectangle`